# Set of Unit Ball’s Extreme Points is not always closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am trying to show that $\operatorname{Ext}B(X)$ does not have to be closed where $B(X)$ is closed unit ball of normed space $X$ and $\operatorname{Ext}B(X)$ is the set of extreme points of unit ball.

My definition for extreme point : $x \in S(X)$ is an extreme point of $B(X)$ if $x$ cannot be written as arithmetic mean of distinct elements of $B(X)$. ($S(X)$ is unit sphere)

I thought that $\Bbb R^n$ can be an example for this and I tried to use $\Bbb R^3$ but I could not find the proper sequence to show that $\operatorname{Ext}B(\Bbb R^3)$ is not closed. I really stuck.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: If you're using the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^n$, every member of the unit sphere is an extreme point of the unit ball.  You'll need a different norm.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957702/compact-set-and-its-extreme-points) and its answer.

Comment: I believe that if the dimension of $B(X)$ is $2$ then the set of extreme points is closed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have to show that $ExtB(X)$ is not closed for a normed space $X$. How does that subset’s convex hull prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C=\operatorname{co} ((\pm 1, 0, \pm 1) \cup \{ (0,y,z)| y^2+z^2 = 1\})$.

The points $\{ (0,y,z)| y^2+z^2 = 1, |y| \neq 1\}$ are extreme, but the points
$(0,0,\pm 1)$ are not.

$C$ is convex, $0 \in C^\circ$ and $C=-C$. Then the Minkowski functional is a norm.

Comment: I cannot link this to being $ExtB(X)$ not closed. Is there any other normed space that I can see set of unit ball’s extreme point is not closed easily?

Comment: The points $(0, \sin {1 \over n}, \cos{1 \over n})$ are extreme but the limit $(0,0,1)$ is not. I can't imagine another normed space having a less complicated structure.

Comment: Thank you so much. Should I use gauge of unit ball as norm?

Comment: @user519955 Yes, that is the Minkowski functional of $C$.

Comment: I need to check, but I believe that in $2$ dimensions that the set of extreme points of the unit ball is always closed, so this is the smallest example in some limited sense.

Comment: I am sorry for writing again but I could not find two points $u$ and $v$ from unit ball such that $(0,0,1)=\dfrac12(u+v)$

Comment: $(0,0,1) = {1 \over 2} ((1,0,1) + (-1,0,1))$.